# Logic Apps / Outlook365 - Send a mail from a Shared Mailbox

Tags: email, office365, azure-logic-apps

I need to send a mail from a Logic Apps by using a Shared Mailbox in the "from".
I have a shared mailbox (noreply@mycompany.com) and I have granted to my user account the permissions "full access", "send as" and also "send on behalf" on the shared mailbox.
In the Logic Apps, I have a Send a mail from a Shared Mailbox (v2) and I use my user account to create the connection.
When I run the Logic Apps, I have a 404 error with the message "Specified folder not found".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I configure the shared mailbox same with you and meet the same problem. In logic app, it always shows `404 Specified folder not found` but I can call graph api to implement it success. So I think it has nothing to do with the permissions.

Here is a workaround for your reference. Use "**Send an email(v2)**" action and set "**From (Send as)**" as the shared mailbox address.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that after setting the permissions, we need to wait for a few minutes/hours (I don't know exactly how many time). On my side, it works after 2 hours.
Sounds like there are some replications or caching somewhere between Logic Apps connectors and Office365 permissions.

Comment: Yes, the configuration of permissions will take some time to take effect(sometimes a few hours).